# Zend\Session\Container annoyingly locks while in use, what's your workaround?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a controller with two actions.  One performs a very long computation, and at several steps, stores status in a session container:

```
public function longAction()
{

    $session = new Container('SessionContainer');
    $session->finished = 0;
    $session->status   = "A";

    // do something long

    $session->status = "B";

    // do more long jobs

    $session->status = "C";

    // ...

}
```

The second controller:

```
public function shortAction()
{

    $session = new Container('SessionContainer');

    return new JsonModel(
        array(
            'status' => $session->status
        )
    );

}
```

These are both called via AJAX, but I can evidence the same behavior in just using browser tabs.  I first call /module/long  which does its thing.  While it completes its tasks, calling /module/short (I thought would just echo JSON) stalls /module/long is done!

Bringing this up, some ZFers felt this was a valid protection against race conditions; but I can't be the only one with this use case that really doesn't care about the latter.

Any cheap tricks that avoid heading towards queues, databases, or memory caches?  Trying to keep it lightweight.

Comment: Those this happen if you use the offset functions, too? `$session->offsetSet('status', $newStatus)` - would be my only idea, not familiar with session too much

Answer (score 0):

this is the expected behavior. this is why:

Sessions are identified using a cookie to store the session id, this allows your browser to pickup the same session on the next request.

As you long process is using sessions, it will not call **session_write_close()** until the whole process execution is complete, meaning the session is still open while the long process is running.

when you connect with another browser tab the browser will try and pickup the same session (using the same cookie) which is still open and running the long process.

If you open the link using a different browser you will see the page will load fine and not wait around for the **session_write_close()** to be called, this is because it's opening a separate session (however you will not see the text you want as it's a separate session)

You could try and manually write and close (session_write_close()) the session, but that's probably not the best way to go about things.

It's definitely worth looking at something like Gearman for this, there's not that much extra work, and it's designed especially for this kind of async job processing. Even writing status to the database would be better, but that's still not ideal.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Andrew.  Gearman wouldn't immediately solve the problem though, since the gearman process would be sandboxed from the session cookies.  I've resorted to using Memcached to exchange strings.